# What does the nmap -p- command do?

Tags: nmap

I just started using hack the box and I find it confusing which nmap commands are being used and why. Most of the time they use `nmap -sV {Target IP}` but other times they use `nmap -p- -sv {Target IP}`.

I tried looking through the command lists but I don't see any -p- attribute, what exactly is this scan doing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure -p is used to specify a port range.  Not all the options are listed on the man page.

Comment: `-p` is used to specify a port range. `-p` scans all 65534 ports. By default (without `-p`) nmap scans only the 1000 most common ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-p-` is for scanning all the 65535 ports.

From `man nmap`:

```
-p port ranges (Only scan specified ports)
           ...
           So you can specify -p- to scan ports from 1 through 65535.
           ...
```